# rails html tag indentation in haml clearfication. Ajax only work once after refresh or ajax work find but FOCU

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I just started using haml in my rails app and I understand how much of a pain that is dealing with indentation. Anyhow I was trying to solve the Flash of Unstyled Content(FOCU) problem when I was going through pages through links without using Ajax. I come across with HTML to haml convert and I realized the html tag in my application.html.haml is off from the converter and the one that I wrote. So I tried both and see what happens. I wasn't sure why is like that and how i should solve it. hoping if anyone can point me to the right direction. I included my javascript files just incase 
thank you

In my view/layout/application.html.haml (this version ajax work perfectly fine but FOCU)

```
!!! 5
%html
%head      <----------- no indented
  %title= process
  = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
  = javascript_include_tag 'jquery', 'application', "data-turbolinks-track" => true
  = csrf_meta_tags
```

The convert told me that it should be (this version ajax work once after refresh but no FOCU)

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head      <----------- indented
    %title= process
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'jquery', 'application', "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
```

my process.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[name='process']").on("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/process/process_table',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.main_container').html(data);
                return false
            }
        });
        history.pushState(null,"", "index");
    });
});
```

my javascripts/application.js

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
});
```

Comment: I would advise you to keep your layouts as html.erb, it's easier for layouts (and does it fix your current problem?). Then you can convert all your views to html.haml. PS: with a good IDE indentation in haml files is very easy, perhaps you should look that way

Comment: I tried both sublime with haml plug in and rubymine. Both of them didn't flag me for that indentation... maybe I will try that. but I was just thinking that must be a way and i want to understand what it means

Comment: @AirWick219 Second method is the correct version, i have used it too and if you look at it <head> and <body> tags are always inside <html> tag hence they should be indented. What is the problem with using 2nd option? i didn't get it?